# How can I translate the captions of the TOpenDialog/TSaveDialog dialogs in Delphi 11.1.5?

Tags: delphi, translation, topendialog, tsavedialog

I could translate the `Captions[]` and `ButtonCaptions[]` used by `MessageDlg` if I set the appropriate constants in the `Vcl.Consts.pas`.
But as I can see there is no such an easy solution like this for `TOpenDialog` and `TSaveDialog`. These are Windows controls and something more tricky solution needed. I tried the `FindComponent` on the created dialog and the `fFileDialog` in the created wrapper (during the Execute call). But the debugger says : the `ComponentCount` is 0 for both components.

How could I translate these dialogs?

It is not a problem to modify the `Vcl.Dialogs.pas` because my program uses a copy of this (I had to modify it yet for another reasons)

Comment: Use `TFileOpenDialog` and `TFileSaveDialog`.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand It looks a half solution. There are properties for `Title` and `OKButtonLabel` but what about the `Cancel` button? The `dlg.Dialog : IFileDialog` does not define a method to set it.

Comment: You are displaying dialogs that are provided by the OS, not the VCL. So, they are already localized by the OS to the user's locale. If you need to change that, you will have to manipulate the dialogs at the Win32 API layer. Look at [`IFileDialogCustomize.SetControlLabel()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifiledialogcustomize-setcontrollabel), for instance.